# std::cin in an Array

Tags: c++

I am a CS student trying to grasp some C++ basic concepts.
I am trying to get the input of a user from std::cin and put it to an array.

example :

Input > ab ba cd[Entey key pressed]
then I would like the array to contain [ab][ba][cd].

So far I have :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Please give all strings seperated with white space (eg. ab ba cd) : ";
    std::string input[12];
    int i=0;

    while(std::cin >> input[i])
    {
        if(input[i].compare("\n")) break;
        i++;
    }
    //This will print contents of input[].
    for(int k = 0 ; k < 12 ; k++)
    {
        std::cout << "input[" << k << "] = " << input[k] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately this only stores the first string (in this example "ab") in the first index of the array.

If I comment out the if(input[i].compare("\n")) break; a Segmentation fault will be produced. I guess because I exceed the memory allocated for the array and write in a place i shouldnt.

From what I understand so far std::cin will first put ab in input[0] of the array, and keep the remaining string [ba cd] in the stream, then on the next loop (after i++) [ba cd] will still be in the stream, cin will not read further from the keyboard (since something is on the stream) and it should put the string ba on input[1], etc. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Note : This is not homework. My course starts in about 1 month. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::string::compare does not return a boolean value -- it returns an int.  This is used for sorting strings.  It will return <0 if the left string is less, >0 if the right string is less, and 0 if they are the same.  0 is the same as boolean false, so your if statement is actually breaking whenever the string is NOT "\n" -- which is why you break out of the loop on the first iteration.

Also, cin will not give you the newline character -- so checking for "\n" will not work.  Using getline will help you here.

This page is very useful for using cin/cout, istream/ostream, istringstream/ostringstream: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/

I keep it in my bookmarks, and use it periodically.

So, here's probably what you want to do:

```
#include <sstream>
std::string line;
getline(std::cin, line);  // get the entire line

// parse each string from the line
std::istringstream stream(line);
for (int i=0; stream.good(); i++) {
  stream >> input[i];
}
```

Note that you should also try to allow more than 12 input strings without crashing, which can be done with a vector:

```
// parse each string from the line
std::vector< std::string > input;
std::istringstream stream(line);
while (stream.good())
{
  std::string temp;
  stream >> temp;
  input.push_back(temp);
}
```

The vector will dynamically grow as you add new strings to it.  It's kind of like a "smarter" array in that sense -- you don't need to know it's full size at the start.  You can build it up a piece at a time.

Comment: Thanks. It did what I wanted. I had to #include <sstream> though as I got error: variable ‘std::istringstream stream’ has initializer but incomplete type. Thanks again!

Comment: Why not the idiomatic `while(stream >> input[i])` / `while(stream >> temp)`?

Comment: @Cubbi - personal preference, on two accounts.  I prefer "for" over "while" when possible -- it limits the scope of the index to the smallest scope (which is generally preferable).  Also, I've seen too many bugs introduced by trying to condense code, and doing actual work in the "while" conditional.  By keeping it to just a boolean, the code is clearer, which is better for maintenance.  Your suggestion works just as well, but it comes down to preference (and a rigid coding standard at my last job).

Comment: I would bet that there were many more bugs introduced by checking the stream state before the input operation and ignoring the return value of `operator>>`/`getline()` (or forgetting to do the check *after*). But I do agree about limiting scope, the temp variables always declared before the while() in Stroustrup's examples bug me too.

Comment: @Cubbi: excellent points.  Yes, I've seen bugs from not checking return value (or in one case, trying to check, but screwing it up badly).

Answer (score 3):

One obvious problem you could have with that code is that spaces are taken as delimitiers, so probably you're not going to obtain the desired behaviour.

```
#include <iomanip>

...
cin << ws;
```

... before reading anything. This will probably eliminate the problem with whitespaces, though, I would prefer to read the string in other way:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

...
string str;
getline( cin, str );
```

This way, you'll never have the problem of buffer overrum with your vector.

Comment: This would store the input to one string though. So you suggest save the input to one string, and then try to decompose the substrings (words which have whitespaces between them in this case) and put the substrings into an array. I thought about that as well but I was wondering if it is possible like that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector`.

```
std::string tmp_str;
std::vector<std::string> input_array;

while(std::cin.peek() != '\n' &&  std::cin >> tmp_str) {
    input_array.push_back(tmp_str);
}
```